# How to modify environment variables using Python script

Tags: python, environment-variables

I want to edit the path variable using Python , I have tried the following code

```
 Import os 
 os.environ['path'] = r"c/users/filename"
```

The code runs but nothing happens

Comment: What do you mean "nothing happens"? How would you know? There's nothing in that code which verifies that the environment has been modified. If you're expecting that code to modify its _parent's_ environment, sorry, that's not possible: inheritance is a one-way thing. Child processes inherit a copy of their parent's environment, any changes they make will affect the child's children, but cannot affect the parent.

Comment: so , is there no way of modifying parent's environment

Comment: Only by running code directly in that parent process. Eg, in Bash you can't modify the parent's environment via a script run in the normal way, you have to use the `source` command which runs the script in the current process instead of in a subshell.